# Trimble 7X GNSS point Z returns negative elevations

Tags: gps, elevation, datum, vertical-transformation

I have a newly acquired Trimble 7X (with a centimeter kit).  I collected a point in an area with a clear view of the sky. The accuracy indicator showed 1" accuracy and post processing and a differential correction places the point spot on when displayed over imagery.  The settings on the Trimble are set to return Z values in heights above the ellipsoid in meters and output x and y in lat and long.

I have LiDAR data for this area referencing NAVD88. I would like to convert the Z values returned from the Trimble to NAVD88.  I tried this conversion using NOAA's vDATUM.

Here is the post process GNSS data in lat, long, & Z 
(48.793770753, -122.612074293, -16.756m)

The LiDAR elevation at this locations is 4.673m NAVD88.

Below is a screen shot of the vDatum output.  The returned height is not even close to the LiDAR NAVD88 height in this location. My question is why is the GNSS Z value converted to NAVD88 so different from the vDatum value?  Am I doing something wrong in vDatum or am I expecting too much from the Trimble?

[image]

Comment: Check on the geoid model under the Vertical Target and set it to GEOID12B, although I got 5.513 when I set the ellipsoidal dates to 1997.0.

Comment: Thanks  @mkennedy.  That is useful information.  The real error in my z values was a result of using the default geoid model in Trimble GPS Pathfinder Office.  I only have Pathfinder v5.2 and do not have 12B available as an export option.  Setting the Pathfinder geoid to Geoid09 (conus) and doing the vDatum conversion with source NAVD88 with the appropriate geoids brought the Z values within the tolerance of my 3 available LiDAR datasets.

Comment: Excellent! Feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error in the Trimble Z values was a result of accepting the default geoid model inside of Trimble GPS Pathfinder Office during export.  Doing a differential correction on the rover file and exporting the corrected rover file to an ESRI shapefile using geoid09 (conus) returned z values within the range of the LiDAR data and further refined those Z values using the correct geoid settings in vDatum.

To change the geoid settings in Pathfinder Office on data export do the following:

1. Open *Utilities - Export*
2. Choose *Properties* button.
3. From the *Export Setup Properties* window select the *Change* button.
4. Select the *Mean Sea Level (MSL)* radio button.
5. Select the *Other Geoid* radio button.
6. Choose the desired geoid.

Note that my version of Trimble GPS Pathfinder Office (v5.2) did not have an option to choose geoid 12A or 12B but my sales rep's most recent release of the software did have those as export geoid choices.  Downloading 12a and 12b geoid models from [this Trimble site](http://www.trimble.com/globalTRLTAB.asp?Nav=Collection-71) and placing the resulting .ggf files in this directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Trimble\GeoData" of other geoid models did not make 12A or 12B available in Pathfinder office.