# Recording GEOID altitude instead of ellipsoid

Tags: qfield, altitude, geoid

The Trimble receiver is capable of outputting the geoidal height. But for the whole thing to work, I have to do the conversion with Qfield. so far so good - the display shows the correct altitude. I have created some fields that register the x and y coordinates by entering the variables $x, $y. For the height I entered z(@position_coordinate) but it records the ellipsoidal height.

How do I save the converted height?

Comment: You can force your Trimble to record geoid heights so no conversion should be necessary in QGIS.  See the answer here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286384/trimble-7x-gnss-point-z-returns-negative-elevations

Comment: More information would be useful - what Trimble receiver are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I use Trimble Catalyst DA2. The device already converts the ellipsoidal altitude into an orthometric one, but I was not able to store this altitude in Qfield. So I used the Qfield way and it worked, but as I said I don't have the variable to store this height or the variable to store the orthometric height from the device. Thank you for your support.
Kind regards Christian