# Convert GPS heights to AHD

Tags: gps, qfield, datum, qfieldsync

My workplace is looking to replace our Geo 7X and TerraSync. We are looking to replace the Geo 7X with the Trimble DA2 and replace TerraSync with QField.

I'm currently trying to test **QField** and see if it meets all our requirements. One of those requirements is capturing heights on points. I assume when the Z coordinate is captured it is captured in WGS84 but I want it to be captured in AHD.

Is this something that can be done on the fly or would it need to be done in post-processing? And how do I go about it?

Comment: Can we confirm AHD is (Australian Height Datum) ?

Comment: Are you test Qfield against height values with the 7X or with the DA2?  If you are on the 7x then yes, the default Z values would be the EGS84 ellipsoid.  You can alter the vertical datum on the 7x but I am unsure about the DA2 steps.  See here for help with te 7x: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286384/trimble-7x-gnss-point-z-returns-negative-elevations  Maybe the gff files for AHD are available at the link provided in the answer.

Comment: @Mapperz Yes it is Australian Height Datum